# LIKE query by best match by column

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have a table named **customers** and running query as below

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email LIKE '%ab%' OR first_name LIKE '%ab%';
```

The result is as below.

```
------+-------+-------+------- +
|      email    | first_name   |
+-----+-------+-------+------- +
| abc@gmail.com |   xyz        |
| xyz@gmail.com |   abc        |
+-----+-------+-------+--------+
```

What I need is, the **first_name** is best match for search keyword. So I need that row first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to add an order by:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers 
WHERE email LIKE '%ab%' OR first_name LIKE '%ab%'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN first_name LIKE '%ab%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END;
```